# Pry-proof graphic password authentification?

Tags: authentication, passwords, authorization

About 3 years ago there was news at programmers' circles on invention of such graphic password entry scheme, but I haven't been able to google out any tail of this story so far, could you please provide a reference to this news/algo?

The story is about the following: the Site presents a simple graphic picture (a puzzle) to the User, the User quickly solves it with the mouse using a publicly known algo, the Site lets him in. And the algo's killing feature is that prying on the puzzle solving process DOES NOT allow the Pryer to restore the password and/or repeat the entry by himself.